# How to send a command to tmux-session of remote-device (using ssh)

Tags: ssh, command-line, arch-linux, tmux, openssh

On my vanila Arch Linux system, I can send to local `tmux-session` (session `main`) using:

```
$ tmux send -t main.0 'echo asdf' ENTER
```

I can  also send commands to a remote machine using `ssh`: (just for the demonstration, I'm using `localhost`):

```
$ ssh garid@localhost "ls /home"
```

I want to send command to `tmux-session` in `remote-machine` from my terminal (something like following):

```
$ ssh -t garid@localhost "tmux send -t main.0 'echo asdf' ENTER"
```

But it outputs the following error:

```
error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)
Connection to localhost closed.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems you don't have a `tmux` session running on the remote machine, at least not with that name.  What does `ssh garid@localhost tmux ls` output?

Comment: `tmux ls` outputs `qwerty: 1 windows (created Mon Sep 12 15:06:06 2022)` and, 
`ssh garid@localhost "tmux ls"` outputs
`error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Are you using a Unix that somehow sandboxes the `/tmp` directory of each user?

Comment: But I just confirmed that when Using remote machine not my localhost `ssh pi@192.168.43.12 "tmux send -t sess.0 'echo asf' ENTER"` , Everything works. 
So in a sense, everything I expected to work with remote machine works. Should have tested with remote machine first (rather than using localhost)

Comment: Yes, that's what I found when I tested it too. This is why I was wondering whether your local Unix (whatever it is) might isolate the `/tmp` directory for each logged-in user. I believe I've seen that behaviour in some Linuxes, for example.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Sorry I don't know about the sandboxing `/tmp`. (if it helps: my localhost is on vanilla `Arch`)

Comment: It seems `/tmp` isn't isolated. `$ diff <(ssh garid@localhost "ls /tmp") <(ls /tmp)`  shows nothing (i.e. `/tmp` `garid@localhost:/tmp` are identicall) right?

Comment: That would be more interesting if you first made sure to create a file in `/tmp` so that you know that the directory has at least one visible file.

Comment: Ah, sorry to mention that there there are multiple files (~10 ish) were in `/tmp` when I tested it. (they showed up in both `ls /tmp` and `ssh garid@localhost "ls /tmp"`)

Comment: from man page > `tmux stores the server socket in a directory under TMUX_TMPDIR or /tmp if it is unset.` apparently my tmux uses $TMUX_TMPDIR directory. My session files were in `/run/user/1000/tmux-1000/mytmuxtest`. So my guess is, when I try to send over `ssh` that tmux tries to find the session from `/tmp` not from `TMUX_TMPDIR`.

Comment: That could well be the thing. Try `ssh garid@localhost env TMUX_TMPDIR="$TMUX_TMPDIR" tmux ls`.

Comment: YEP, that is it: `env TMUX_TMPDIR="$TMUX_TMPDIR"` does the job. Now I can send the commands. Thanks.

Comment: @Kusalananda Do you to write this solution as an answer, so I can accept your answer as the correct one, and we can close this question?

Comment: If nobody else does, I will do so in a short while. I wonder what sets that variable for you. It's probably in a `bash_profile` file or somewhere else that is only sourced by an interactive login shell.

Comment: apparently, in my `~/.config/shell/profile` there is a line:`export TMUX_TMPDIR="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"` (where it's `/run/user/1000`). 
my configs from [Larbs](https://larbs.xyz/). It's my bad that I didn't know about my env variables in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, [we've confirmed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716978/how-to-send-a-command-to-tmux-session-of-remote-device-using-ssh?noredirect=1#comment1359147_716978) that the intended command,

```bash
ssh remote "tmux send -t main.0 'echo asdf' ENTER"
```

... works when `remote` is not the local host.

We have also [confirmed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716978/how-to-send-a-command-to-tmux-session-of-remote-device-using-ssh?noredirect=1#comment1359188_716978) that the reason the command fails when connecting to `localhost` is that the `TMUX_TMPDIR` variable is unset in the SSH session.  This environment variable is used by `tmux` to determine where a directory containing its control socket should be created.  If the variable is unset, the utility will use `/tmp`.

The variable is unset when you execute `tmux` via `ssh` because the session is a non-interactive non-login session.  As such, it does not source your `~/.config/shell/profile` file which sets the `TMUX_TMPDIR` variable to something other than `/tmp`.  This file is pulled in by [LARBS](https://larbs.xyz), which you use, but of which I know nothing.

You now have a few possible ways to move forward:

1. Do nothing; The intended target of the `ssh`+`tmux` command was never the local host.
2. Ensure that the `TMUX_TMPDIR` variable is set correctly when calling the command on `localhost`;  You may do this with

   ```bash
   ssh localhost "env TMUX_TMPDIR='$TMUX_TMPDIR' tmux send -t main.0 'echo asdf' ENTER"
   ```

   ... but it would assume that the value of the variable locally is the correct value for the other host, so it would be unlikely to be a generic solution.  Connecting with `ssh` to `localhost` is such an unusual thing to do anyway, so rather than doing it this way, loop back to the first point and don't do anything about it, or ...
3. Reset the value of `TMUX_TMPDIR` to the default `/tmp` locally by modifying `~/.config/shell/profile` (set the variable to `/tmp` or comment out the assignment completely); I don't know how this may play with LARBS, though.